# grep on specific file types

Tags: bash, function

I have the following bash function and want to pass my own file
types to the function.  I wonder how should I do it.

```
greprc ()
  {
       grep -hir --exclude=\*.el --include=\*.{org,texi} "$@"
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking [How to pass parameters to function in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298706/how-to-pass-parameters-to-function-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: It is more about how to pass variables to the grep command for --include and --exclude.  Perhaps I can pass them as parameters to the function using the full `--exclude=\*.el --include=\*.{org,texi}` string?